# Alignment problems in HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a simple login/signup page that im making. Both the login and signup parts of the site have issues in that the text mentioning what to write in the textboxes are not aligned with one another. I have tried to change the margins back and forth and no matter how I change it I still have the same problem.

[image: Error in alignment]

As you can see the Password in the login parn and the City and Email part dont stick to the left as it should. Is there any good way of solving this issue? And also is there any "clean" way of pairing the text with the textbox so that they always align? Below you will find the code I use for this part of the site.

```css
/* -------------------------------- The body and div placement ------------------------------ */

#Body {
  text-align: center;
}

#Window_Container {
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 100 auto;
}

#Logo_and_Slogan {
  background-image: url("wimage.png");
  height: inherit;
  width: 340px;
  float: left;
}

#Login_and_Sign_Up {
  height: inherit;
  width: 250px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  float: right;
}

#Login {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: aquamarine;
  height: 120px;
}

#Sign_Up {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: brown;
  height: 270px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}


/* -------------------------------- Modification of the form part        ------------------------------ */

input {
  float: right;
  margin: 3px 0 0 0;
}

select {
  float: right;
  margin: 3px 0 0 0;
}

label {
  float: left;
  margin: 5px 0 0 0;
}

h2 {
  margin: 0 0 2px 0;
  padding: 3px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
   <link href="welcome.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
   <script src="client.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="serverstub.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="Window_Container">
        <div id="Logo_and_Slogan"></div>
        <div id="Login_and_Sign_Up">
            <div id="Login">
                <h2>Login</h2>
                <form action="/action_page.php">
                    <label>Email</label> <input type="text" name="email"><br>
                    <label>Password</label> <input type="password" name="password"><br>
                    <br><input type="submit" value="Submit">
                </form> 
            </div>
            <div id="Sign_Up">
                <h2>Signup</h2>
                <form action="/action_page.php">
                    <label>First name</label> <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
                    <label>Family name</label> <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
                    <label>Gender</label>  <select name="gender">
                                <option value="male">Male</option>
                                <option value="female">Female</option>
                            </select><br>
                    <label>City</label> <input type="text" name="city"><br>
                    <label>Country</label> <input type="text" name="country"><br>
                    <label>Email</label> <input type="text" name="email"><br>
                    <label>Password</label> <input type="password" name="password"><br>
                    <label>Repeat PSW</label> <input type="password" name="passwordrepeat"><br>
                    <br><br><br><input type="submit" value="Submit">
                    </form> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: @giorio that doesn't solve the issue completely.

Comment: @giorgio You can use better language here. How about that *screws* it all up?

Comment: If you're depending on `float`, you're gonna need some `clear`s.

Comment: Added the entire html code and removed the divs from before and after each label and input pair since they make no difference at this moment.

Comment: You need to add a clear both to your labels if you want them to always start on a new line.  I would also make your labels inline-block and give them a width so they do not encroach on the inputs side

Comment: @DanielBeck setting clear: left on the br tags worked magic thank you!

Comment: @Pete is there any benefit to clearing the lables instead of clearing the br tags?

Comment: I wasn't sure if clears worked on `br` tags - I knew you could add a clear attribute in html4 but thought you could only use clear css on block elements.  If it works then I would keep them on the br tag but clear both as you float left and right - they both need clearing

Comment: @Pete Spot on, clear: both made everything fall in line even better!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `clear: left;` to `label`, this will prevent one label moving right of another one (as its the case with "Gender" and "City")

```css
/* -------------------------------- The body and div placement ------------------------------ */

#Body {
  text-align: center;
}

#Window_Container {
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 100 auto;
}

#Logo_and_Slogan {
  background-image: url("wimage.png");
  height: inherit;
  width: 340px;
  float: left;
}

#Login_and_Sign_Up {
  height: inherit;
  width: 250px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  float: right;
}

#Login {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: aquamarine;
  height: 120px;
}

#Sign_Up {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: brown;
  height: 270px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}


/* -------------------------------- Modification of the form part        ------------------------------ */

input {
  float: right;
  margin: 3px 0 0 0;
}

select {
  float: right;
  margin: 3px 0 0 0;
}

label {
  float: left;
  margin: 5px 0 0 0;
  clear: left;
}

h2 {
  margin: 0 0 2px 0;
  padding: 3px;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
   <link href="welcome.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
   <script src="client.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="serverstub.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="Window_Container">
        <div id="Logo_and_Slogan"></div>
        <div id="Login_and_Sign_Up">
            <div id="Login">
                <h2>Login</h2>
                <form action="/action_page.php">
                    <label>Email</label> <input type="text" name="email"><br>
                    <label>Password</label> <input type="password" name="password"><br>
                    <br><input type="submit" value="Submit">
                </form> 
            </div>
            <div id="Sign_Up">
                <h2>Signup</h2>
                <form action="/action_page.php">
                    <label>First name</label> <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
                    <label>Family name</label> <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
                    <label>Gender</label>  <select name="gender">
                                <option value="male">Male</option>
                                <option value="female">Female</option>
                            </select><br>
                    <label>City</label> <input type="text" name="city"><br>
                    <label>Country</label> <input type="text" name="country"><br>
                    <label>Email</label> <input type="text" name="email"><br>
                    <label>Password</label> <input type="password" name="password"><br>
                    <label>Repeat PSW</label> <input type="password" name="passwordrepeat"><br>
                    <br><br><br><input type="submit" value="Submit">
                    </form> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Addition: I made the form containers 20px wider and therefore the left container 20px narrower to avoid the problem described for Chrome in the comments.

Comment: Your snippet looks all messed up to me. The `male` select is under "Gender", the last `input` is glued to the right of the submit button...

Comment: @JeremyThille Hmm - here it looks perfect. I wonder what it is that makes the difference. Which browser and OS are you on?

Comment: Chrome and windows 7

Comment: @Johannes Exactly what needed to be done, as I discussed with Pete in the comments above putting a clear: both to the br tag worked magic.

Comment: @JeremyThille just make the container a little bit wider - obviously the input fields in chrome are wider by default and don't fit into ine line with the longer labels ("Family Name" and "Repeat PSW"), the awkward shifting then is caused by that fact and by the float settings.

Comment: Why would _I_ make your container wider? Will you tell your clients, "Meh, my layout is broken, but just make my container a bit wider in Chrome"? No, your code has to work.

Comment: So make the container wider, not just for chrome, but for all browsers. It won't hurt the other browsers... It's not my container, BTW ;-)

Comment: But why do you keep telling _me_ to make _your_ container wider? It's _your_ code, it's your snippet, not mine, it has to work in your client's browsers :)

Comment: What makes you think I downvoted your answer? Because I didn't.

Answer (score 3):

As usual, what is a pain to do with classic CSS (float, clear etc) is a breeze with Flexbox :

```css
#Login_and_Sign_Up {
  height: inherit;
  width: 250px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  float: right;
}

#Login {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #7fffd4;
  padding: 5px;
}

#Sign_Up {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #a52a2a;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
}

form div {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: #00f dashed 1px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}

form div input {
  width: 120px;
}

form div select {
  width: 124px;
}
```

```html
<div id="Login_and_Sign_Up">

  <div id="Login">
    <h2>Login</h2>
    <form action="/action_page.php">
      <div><label>Email</label> <input type="text" name="email"></div>
      <div><label>Password</label> <input type="password" name="password"></div>
      <br><input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </div>
  
  <div id="Sign_Up">
    <h2>Signup</h2>
    <form action="/action_page.php">
      <div><label>First name</label> <input type="text" name="fname"></div>
      <div><label>Family name</label> <input type="text" name="lname"></div>
      <div><label>Gender</label>
        <select name="gender">
            <option value="male">Male</option>
            <option value="female">Female</option>
    </select></div>
      <div><label>City</label> <input type="text" name="city"></div>
      <div><label>Country</label> <input type="text" name="country"></div>
      <div><label>Email</label> <input type="text" name="email"></div>
      <div><label>Password</label> <input type="password" name="password"></div>
      <div><label>Repeat PSW</label> <input type="password" name="passwordrepeat"></div>
      <br><input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can us tabular forms, they are **easy to manage.**

```css
form{
background-color:red
}
H1{
text-align:center
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<H1>Hello</H1>
<form>
  <table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>Email</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="firstname"></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Password</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="firstname"></td>
  </tr>

</table>

  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I also use tables, they're super-robust for layouts, but for some reason, most developers will tell you not to use them.

Comment: tabular layouts are extremely efficient, they load synchronously and are an ambient way to produce cool layouts

Comment: @JeremyThille thanks for the input. Though I believe in only providing hints to a question, will provide detail answer next time :)

Comment: "for some reason, most developers will tell you not to use them"  It's fun watching history go round in circles.  Tables initially got a bad reputation because people didn't want to learn CSS and used overcomplicated tables for layout.  It got to the point where people would sniff at you for even using tables for tabular data.

Answer (score 1):

Let's do some cleanup and simplification here.

First off we'll get rid of all those `<br>` tags.  Don't need 'em.

Next we're going to stop with the `float`s.  Float is great for what it's intended for, which is letting text wrap around a floated element. Float is not so great for what it's often used for, which is as a bad replacement for `inline-block` -- bad because you have to set explicit heights, worry about `clear`s, etc.

```css
#Login_and_Sign_Up {
  width: 250px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

#Login {
  background-color: aquamarine;
}

#Sign_Up {
  background-color: brown;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

label {
  width: 80px;  /* adjust to taste */
  display:inline-block
}
```

```html
<div id="Login_and_Sign_Up">
  <div id="Login">
    <h2>Login</h2>
    <form action="#">
      <div><label>Email</label> <input type="text" name="email"></div>
      <div><label>Password</label> <input type="password" name="password"></div>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </div>
  <div id="Sign_Up">
    <h2>Signup</h2>
    <form action="/action_page.php">
      <div><label>First name</label> <input type="text" name="fname"></div>
      <div><label>Family name</label> <input type="text" name="lname"></div>
      <div><label>Gender</label> 
        <select name="gender">
          <option value="male">Male</option>
          <option value="female">Female</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div><label>City</label> <input type="text" name="city"></div>
      <div><label>Country</label> <input type="text" name="country"></div>
      <div><label>Email</label> <input type="text" name="email"></div>
      <div><label>Password</label> <input type="password" name="password"></div>
      <div><label>Repeat PSW</label> <input type="password" name="passwordrepeat"></div>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Further improvements that could be made:

For accessibility you should be associating your `<label>`s with their form elements.  Do this either by using the `for` attribute on the label, or by nesting the form fields inside the label.

Using the label as the wrapper would have the additional advantage of allowing you to omit the wrapper `<div>`s, by setting `label` to `display:block`.

Answer (score 0):

> Use CSS Flexbox

I have done it for the login form, you can repeat the same for sign-up as well.
Please wrap your `'label` and `input` `select` in `<p>` tags. This will help you eliminate `<br/>` tags.

```css
    #Body {
      text-align: center;
    }

    #Window_Container {
      width: 600px;
      height: 400px;
      margin: 100 auto;
    }

    #Logo_and_Slogan {
      background-image: url("wimage.png");
      height: inherit;
      width: 340px;
      float: left;
    }

    #Login_and_Sign_Up {
      height: inherit;
      width: 250px;
      margin-left: 10px;
      float: right;
    }

    #Login {
      text-align: center;
      background-color: aquamarine;
      height: 170px;
    }

    #Sign_Up {
      text-align: center;
      background-color: brown;
      height: 270px;
      margin-top: 10px;
    }


    /* -------------------------------- Modification of the form part        ------------------------------ */
    .flex-form p{
      display:flex;
    }
    
    input {
      flex: 1;
      margin: 3px 0 0 0;
      float:right;
    }

    select {
      flex: 1;
      margin: 3px 0 0 0;
      float:right;
    }

    label {
      flex: 1;
      margin: 5px 0 0 0;
      float:left;
      text-align:left;
    }

    h2 {
      margin: 0 0 2px 0;
      padding: 3px;
      font-size: 20px;
    }
```

```html
    <html>
    <head>
       <link href="welcome.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
       <script src="client.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
       <script src="serverstub.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="Window_Container">
            <div id="Logo_and_Slogan"></div>
            <div id="Login_and_Sign_Up">
                <div id="Login">
                    <h2>Login</h2>
                    <form action="/action_page.php" class="flex-form">
                        <p>
                            <label>Email</label>
                            <input type="text" name="email">
                        </p>
                        <p>
                            <label>Password</label>
                            <input type="password" name="password">
                        </p>
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                    </form> 
                </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

My example looks at utilizing bootstrap `.form-group` and adding a `min-width` to the label.  Though in hindsight, after reading the flexbox answer - that one is probably easiest for you.  I've spent a little time working on this answer so I'll post it anyway.

I also stipped out a lot of unnecessary tags and assigned labels to their elements.  There was a lot of `br` and `div` which didn't need to be there using this method.

```css
    #Login_and_Sign_Up {
        height: inherit;
        margin-left: 10px;
        /* float: right; */
    }
    
    #Login {
        background-color: aquamarine;
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 300px;
    }
    
    #Sign_Up {
        background-color: brown;
        margin-top: 10px;
        width: 300px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    label {
        min-width: 90px;
    }
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div id="Login_and_Sign_Up">
        <div id="Login">
            <h2>Login</h2>
            <form action="/action_page.php">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                    <input type="text" name="email" id="email">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div id="Sign_Up">
            <h2>Signup</h2>
            <form action="/action_page.php">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="firstname">First name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="fname" id="firstname">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="familyname">Family name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="lname" id="familyname">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="gender">Gender</label>
                    <select name="gender" id="gender">
                <option value="male">Male</option>
                <option value="female">Female</option>
                </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="city">City</label>
                    <input type="text" name="city" id="city">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="country">Country</label>
                    <input type="text" name="country" id="country">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                    <input type="text" name="email" id="email">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="repeat">Repeat PSW</label>
                    <input type="password" name="passwordrepeat" id="repeat">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                </div>

            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```